# USB device disconnected/connected sound plays at random times

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, lenovo-laptop, desktop-icons

I bought a used Lenovo Thinkpad W540 running Windows 10 Professional. Periodically it makes the USB device disconnected sound followed a few seconds later with the USB device connected sound. When the USB device connected sound is played, this icon appears in the Show Hidden Icons space (right side of the dock before the WiFi icon).

*ex. Unknown USB Device Icon*

[image: Icon of unknown USB device that looks like a very tall wine glass laying on its side on a navy background with one small (2 pixels by 2 pixels) with one bright blue square above the wine glass and one below it, to the right of the other square]

Here is the icon in the context of the Show Hidden Icons window:

*ex. Hidden Icons Windows*

[image: The icon in the Show Hidden Icons window]

I have only a Dell mouse connected and the mouse continues to function during the interval between the disconnected sound and the connected sound.

I bought the computer a few weeks ago so it has an unknown history. It doesn't have the DVD drive, just an OEM cover where the drawer should be. And it uses a third party power adapter because the company I bought it from didn't have the original 170 watt adapter that the i7 version of the W540 requires.

I know that the Windows 10 Professional system is a clean installation because I ordered the machine with an upgraded new SSD drive. I ran all of the Windows 10 updates and updated the BIOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use another USB port (2.0 (usually white in color)) with the mouse? 
Your machine has 2x USB 2.0, 2x USB 3.0. Are you sure you are not using the USB 3.0 port 
(usually blue in color)? [you're Lenovo (.pdf) 
https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t540p_w540_ug_en.pdf ] P.S. I have never seen that type of icon before. Is the mouse new? You might want to also try a different mouse.

Comment: The problem may be related to the USB ports and the mouse. I used the computer without the mouse connected today and the problem didn't occur. That means only that I can't eliminate it from the equation. I would continue that experiment but I find this machine's trackpads to be cumbersome to use. (I have used trackpads since laptops featured them and have never found them to be difficult.) I'll use the USB 2 ports, which are color-coded but are closer to the back of the machine.

Comment: I searched the hard drive for *.icon. *.png, and *.bmp but couldn't find that icon. Visual searches on the web didn't yield anything either. I probably won't have any more information to contribute until the problem resumes occurring. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Icons are often packaged inside other files for convenience and cannot be found through simple file searches. Searching for a specific icon is not often a worthwhile task.